# Which scripture is the source of the verse "Janmanā jāyatē jantuḥ karmaṇā jāyatē dvijaḥ" (everyone is born worm)?

Tags: scripture, varna, shloka, reference-request, brahmanas

Complete verse is as follows.

> Janmanā jāyatē jantuḥ karmaṇā jāyatē dvijaḥ |
> vēdādhyayanatō vipraḥ brahmavid brāhmaṇa smr̥taḥ ||

In Devanagari script:

> जन्मना जायते जन्तु: कर्मणा जायते द्विज:।
> वेदाध्ययनतो विप्र: ब्रह्नविदं ब्राह्मण: स्मृत:।।

or

> जन्मना जायते जन्तुः कर्मणा जायते द्विजः ।
> वेदाध्ययनतो विप्रो ब्रह्मविद् ब्राह्मणः स्मृतः ॥

Translation/Meaning: By birth we are animals. From *samskaara* such as upanayana, one becomes a *dwija*. By studying Vedas, one becomes a *vipra*. Only with *brahma vidya* one becomes a Brahmin.

This sloka is usually shared with vaṭu during upanayana. I would love to know if anyone could share more details about it. Thank you!

Edit: The question is similar to the one asked [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17882/which-scripture-is-the-source-of-the-verse-janmana-jayate-shudrah-everyone). However, the sloka cited here is different from that of the question.

Edit 2: While searching online, I could find this sloka in a [blog post](https://mokshopaayasamhitaa.blogspot.com/2020/04/blog-post.html) and a [facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/AKkatipalla/posts/pfbid0Mj5kBFLUKt3eoodrz4ADgfH16QTUvuRdGVJwiQJTrRvzgLfdUSTnnTZwNbGjhJTXl). Including them here for reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which scripture is the source of the verse "janmana jayate shudrah.. " (everyone is born a shudra)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17882/which-scripture-is-the-source-of-the-verse-janmana-jayate-shudrah-everyone)

Comment: @Adiyarkku - Thank you! No. They have similar theme but the sloka in that question is different.