Where does this verse on caste come from?
I saw this statement on social media.
Which scripture does it come from? Which verse?

The verse you are referring to is:
"Janmana jayate shudrah, samskarat bhaved dvijah, vedapathad bhaved
viprah, brahma janati iti brahmanah."
This translates to: "By birth, everyone is a Shudra (unrefined or
uneducated), through samskaras (purification and rites), one becomes a
dvija (twice-born), through Vedic study, one becomes a vipra
(scholar), and by realizing Brahman (the ultimate reality), one
becomes a Brahmana (knower of Brahman)."


Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17882/which-scripture-is-the-source-of-the-verse-janmana-jayate-shudrah-everyone
